# Why does pandas DataFrame.iloc return a scalar for category dtype, but a Series for object dtype?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In pandas 0.23.0 and python 3.6.5, I'm seeing behavior I don't understand when using `iloc[int]` on a DataFrame.

If the DataFrame has only one column, and the type of that column is 'category', `iloc[int]` returns a scalar value instead of a Series.

When the column "answer" is an object dtype, I get a `Series` as expected:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'answer': ['no', 'no', 'yes']})
>>> df['answer'] = df['answer'].astype('object')
>>> df.iloc[0]
answer    no
Name: 0, dtype: object
>>> type(df.iloc[0])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

However, when I change the column to category dtype, I suddenly get a `str`??

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'answer': ['no', 'no', 'yes']})
>>> df['answer'] = df['answer'].astype('category')
>>> df.iloc[0]
'no'
>>> type(df.iloc[0])
<class 'str'>
```

Note that I no longer get scalar values from a DataFrame if it contains more than one column, even if they are all category:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'answer': ['no', 'no', 'yes'], 'name': ['steve', 'john', 'sally']})
>>> df['answer'] = df['answer'].astype('category')
>>> df['name'] = df['name'].astype('category')
>>> df.iloc[0]
answer       no
name      steve
Name: 0, dtype: object
>>> type(df.iloc[0])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Is this the expected behavior?  If so, how can I force `iloc[int]` to return a `Series` regardless of the column types?

Comment: The documentation mentions this behavior as different for category dtypes: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#getting and this works as "expected" `df.iloc[[0], 0]`

Answer (score 1):

After digging through the documentation, it looks like this behavior is expected:

> Returning a single item from categorical data will also return the value, not a categorical of length “1”.
>
> To get a single value Series of type category, you pass in a list with a single value

So this ended up working via `iloc[[0], 0]`:

```
>>> pandas.DataFrame({'answer': ['no', 'no', 'yes']}, dtype='category').iloc[[0], 0]
0    no
Name: answer, dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [no, yes]
>>> type(pandas.DataFrame({'answer': ['no', 'no', 'yes']}, dtype='category').iloc[[0], 0])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Feels strange to me, but at least it's documented.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#getting